Do numbers' readings ever change, such as in「伊【い】58」?
Is the number of a submarine (or airplane, or ship) simply pronounced as a stand-alone number, or does an understood noun after it ever affect its pronunciation?
原爆【げんばく】の運命【うんめい】を変【か】えたかもしれない「伊【い】58【ごじゅうはち】」
The "I-58" may have changed the fate of the atomic bomb.
https://www.fnn.jp/articles/294273
I was wondering because sometimes the number eight changes what comes after it, such as 18歳【じゅうはっさい】, but what if there is an understood 潜水艦【せんすいかん】 after the number? My guess is that the ship's name is read simply as 【いごじゅうはち】. Is that correct?

Since 伊58 is not followed by any counter/unit, you won't see changes like よん becoming よ or ろく becoming ろっ. However, whether to read a code number digit-by-digit (like a telephone number) or as an ordinary natural number depends on the convention of each industry. For submarines in the Imperial Japan era, the convention seems to be to use the natural number reading (ごじゅうはち rather than ごーはち). N700 (shinkansen) is read えぬななひゃく, but Boeing 767 is read ボーイングななろくなな. When in doubt, it's safer to default to the digit-by-digit reading.
Note that when a code number is followed by a kanji like 系, 形 or 式, you may see changes like 16系 (じゅうろっけい) or 700系 (ななひゃっけい). Also note that a few code numbers have well-known "nicknames", such as D51 read as デコイチ.
